# Sails.js Conditional Model Loading

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm looking for a way to conditionally load the models in the `api/models/` folder in a Sails app on `sails.lift()` or `sails.load()`. Ideally, depending on the `NODE_ENV`, those models either would be loaded or wouldn't. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sails.js v1.0 (at least) there is a setting that you can add to your environment config file to disable models from loading:

```
{
  hooks: {
    orm: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After lots of looking and searching, I couldn't find anything that would allow you to conditionally load a model just through the config files or something like that. So what I did instead was this:

```
const model = {
    connection: 'connectionName',
    tableName: 'tableName',
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'objectid',
            columnName: '_id'
        },
        column1: 'string',
        column2: 'string'
    }
};
module.exports = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'environmentName' ? model : {};
```

This way, when the app loads with a specific environment name, it may or may not load the model. There might be other ways to do the same thing, but this was the way I settled on.

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea with the env var!  That's a perfectly valid workaround.

If you're willing to live on the edge a little bit, in Sails v0.12, you can specify a dictionary of model definitions as `sails.config.orm.moduleDefinitions.models`; e.g. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-orm/blob/dc361c49e6054aad844c66f74c6e464a35f106f1/test/initialize-with-models.js#L35-L45

This is still experimental, but it's being used in enough places now that it's likely to become a continued addition to the API, Sails v1 and beyond.